# Why are symbols for classes written in Swift difficult to read in lldb? Is it possible to change this?

Tags: swift, lldb

Some context, I'm new to swift, going through a book right now

When looking at exceptions in lldb, 
when there's a stack frame from a Swift class, the symbol is very hard to read

ex:
`_TFC10MyApp16TestViewControllersP01CBLDocumentModel5queryfzT4viewCSo7CBLView4`

it looks like lldb just doesn't know how to display the signatures properly-- is there a flag or setting I can change?   Or is just a thing that everybody has learned to deal with?

Really the difficult part, for me, is when it prints random letters in the middle of the symbol

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with lldb, it’s called **name mangling** in Swift, and the symbols have [very specific meanings](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABI.rst#mangling). Swift’s name mangling is specifically designed so that the mangled name can be deterministically reconstructed to provide information about the kind of declaration is is, and the scope it lives in, among other things.

Comment: oh sweet, thanks for the link!  the mangle keyword will help a lot 

do you have a recommended way to de-mangle the symbols?

Comment: A [demangling tool](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/tools/swift-demangle) exists that is maintained as part of the Swift compiler, however I have never used it so I can’t be of much help there. I do not develop on Apple platforms, but I believe Apple also ships a proprietary demangling tool that wraps the compiler tool.

Comment: lldb has a command:`language swift demangle` that you can use to demangle symbols.  But lldb will generally demangle symbol names in backtraces, I'm a little surprised you are seeing mangled names.