# Swift stackframe symbols from exceptions logged in lldb are not being demangled

Tags: swift, debugging

This has actually been pretty difficult to deal with, and it was hinted to me that this is not normal?

I inherited this project, so I'm thinking maybe a flag was set somewhere I don't see

Here is a snippet from one of my exceptions:

```
    27  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x0000000102981340 _TFVs15ContiguousArray42_withUnsafeMutableBufferPointerIfSupportedurfzFzTGSpx_Si_qd__GSqqd____merged + 128
    28  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x00000001029709c0 _TFVs15ContiguousArray42_withUnsafeMutableBufferPointerIfSupportedurfzFzTGSpx_Si_qd__GSqqd___ + 64
    29  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x0000000102970972 _TTWurGVs15ContiguousArrayx_s17MutableCollectionsFS0_42_withUnsafeMutableBufferPointerIfSupportedurfzFzTGSpWx8Iterator7Element__Si_qd__GSqqd___ + 34
    30  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x00000001029978ff _TFesRxs17MutableCollectionxs22RandomAccessCollectionrS_4sortfT2byFTWxPs10Collection8Iterator7Element_WxS2_S3___Sb_T_ + 495
    31  libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010299769d _TFEsPs8Sequence6sortedfT2byFTWx8Iterator7Element_WxS0_S1___Sb_GSaWxS0_S1___ + 237
    32  MyApp                          0x00000001001ce414 _TFe10MyAppRxs8SequenceWx8Iterator7Element_s9AnyObjectrS0_6sortedfT17bySortDescriptorsGSaCSo16NSSortDescriptor__GSaWxS1_S2___ + 212
```

Is there a flag or setting that I need to set to un-mangle these Swift symbols?

Or is this something everybody has just been dealing with?

Per @pbergson

Xcode version:

> Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)

Swift version:

> Apple Swift version 3.1 (swiftlang-802.0.53 clang-802.0.42) Target:
>   x86_64-apple-macosx10.9

Optimization Level:

> None, and No's

Other Swift Flags:

> -DDEBUG

Comment: Where is that stack trace from? It looks to me like a crash report I would get from a third party that wasn't symbolicated.

Comment: straight from LLDB, an exception was thrown, `2017-07-26 20:55:52.269186-0400 MyApp[53293:5011533] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Current stack trace:`

Comment: Isn't that what you asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250879/why-are-symbols-for-classes-written-in-swift-difficult-to-read-in-lldb-is-it-po?

Comment: I felt the question was a little more about what was happening, as opposed to how to fix it-- it's been really bothering me so I made a new question with the pertinent details-- before I wasn't even quite sure what I was asking

Answer (score 0):

Yep, that's not normal. There is no flag of which I am aware that you can set to get that result. A couple of questions:

1. What version of Xcode are you using?
2. What version of Swift are you using?
3. Take a look in your project file, in the "Build Settings" tab. One of the settings is "Optimization Level". What level are you using?
4. A few rows down from Optimization Level there's a section for "Swift Compiler - Custom Flags". Is there anything there?

You might also try running a simple project in your Xcode, deliberately get it to crash, and see what the exceptions look like. That will help diagnose whether you have a problem with your specific project, or with your Xcode setup.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I edited the question with the details requested, and will try to test project later this evening!